# Saving data into my Database not possible...App ends

Tags: android, sql, save

Hey everyone ;) I have a new question again :D 
I can open my app now and insert the data into the fields, but as soon as i click the save-menu-item it aborts ... i posted the piece of code at the end of which i think where the error lies. 
Hope you can help me ;)

```
//KFZ-Daten updaten (UPDATE)        
                if(getIntent().hasExtra("id") == true)
                {
                    long l = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("id");
                    myDB.execSQL("UPDATE "+wechsel.MY_DB_TABLE+" SET "+
                            "name = '"+KfzName.getText().toString()+"', "+
                        "model = '"+KfzModel.getText().toString()+"', "+
                        "bemerkungen ='"+KfzBemerkungen.getText().toString()+"', "+
                        "kraftstoffart ='"+i+"', "+
                        "tankinhalt = '"+KfzTankinhalt.getText().toString()+"' "+
                        "WHERE _id = "+l+";"); 
                }
//Neues KFZ in Datenbank speichern (INSERT)             
                else
                {                   
                    myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+wechsel.MY_DB_TABLE+"name,"+ 
                                                                       "model,"+ 
                                                                       "bemerkungen,"+ 
                                                                       "kraftstoffart,"+ 
                                                                       "tankinhalt) "
                            +"VALUES ('"+KfzName.getText().toString()+"',"+
                            "'"+KfzModel.getText().toString()+"',"+
                            "'"+KfzBemerkungen.getText().toString()+"',"+
                            "'"+i+"',"+"'"+
                                               KfzTankinhalt.getText().toString()+"');");
                }
                finish();
                return true;    
            }
            else
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte geben Sie einen Namen für das Fahrzeug ein!", 
                                                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the `logcat` output :]

Comment: Post your logcat. You should also use binds in your SQL statements so you don't have to do that single quote mess you have right now.

Comment: 02-02 17:16:30.419: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.mflow.ContainerHelper.run(ContainerHelper.java:46)

Comment: 02-02 17:16:30.419: WARN/System.err(22536): java.lang.Exception: You must call com.mercuryintermedia.productconfiguration.initialize() first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing an opening paren in the `INSERT` statement just before the name field:

```
                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+wechsel.MY_DB_TABLE+" (name,"+
```

Comment: all right, now i was able to insert one which i can not select to view the characteristics, but i don't get the update option and i can't insert a second one...

Comment: @Sam: It's not clear to me from the posted code what is happening. One thing to look at might be to make sure the `_id` field is set to the desired value.  Is it an auto-increment?  I see that it is not in the INSERT statement.